# Spring Equation Correctedness

Tags: physics

A mass .60 $\mathit{kg}$ is attached to a spring with a spring constant of 130 $\mathit{\frac{N}{m}}$. There are no non-conservative forces acting, and the system is stretched .13 $\mathit{m}$.  Find the force when it is instaneous released.

$$$$
From here is made the decision of calculating it like this:

\begin{align}
\mathbf{Force} &= -k \triangle x \\
&= -130 \ \cdot \ .13 = -16.9 \mathit{N}
\end{align}

Using that same expression for Force I calculated the acceleration in the x-axis:

\begin{align}
F_{\mathit{Hooke's\ Law}}&= F_{\mathit{net}} \\
\frac{-k \triangle x}{m} &= a_{net} \\
\frac{-16.9}{.60} &= 30 \mathit{\frac{m}{s^2}}
\end{align}

### Correction:

$a_{net} = 28 \mathit{\frac{m}{s^s}}$

Is my attempt correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That looks right, but you may want to write
$$\frac{-16.9}{0.60}\approx 28 \frac{\text{m}}{\text{s}^2}$$
instead of $30 \text{m}/\text{s}^2$, since the actual value is $28.166...$ which is closer to $28$.

Comment: Yes your right I rounded incorrectly since I thought there was two sig figs.